# JSON deserialization & serialization

Tags: json, apex, json-deserialization

I am working on one JSON payload and trying to deserialize it but not getting any value after deserialization

Here is my payload

```
{
    "01/01/2010":{
        "Frequency":3,
        "term": 24
    },
    "01/01/2011":{
        "Frequency":6,
        "term": 12
    },
    "01/01/2012":{
        "Frequency":1,
        "term": 36
    }
}
```

I create class for this

```
public class CustomWrapper {
    public Date date1 {get;set;}
    public class Parameter{
        public integer Frequency {get;set;}
        public integer term {get;set;}
        
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me if I am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Specify programming language. It is C#?

Comment: Use `Dictionary`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov this class is in Apex. what is Dictionary ?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/27165

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderPetrov ! This helps me perform operation which I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing which library you're using or the code to deserialize it, my guess would be that it's having trouble with Date. Technically the datestamp is a string and you need to provide some format string to turn that into an actual date object.

Comment: Thank you @nickP for your response. Class is in Apex language. Can you please provide some sample example ?